# Smart Contract is not working on Geth private network, while it does work on Ganache as well as Remix

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, ganache

I've only begun working with geth from last week and have faced the quite a challenge. I've written a smart contract and it works on remix (JavaScript VM) but somehow it does not work on my geth private network.

I've tried to deploy the same smart contract on Ganache and it worked fine.

I really don't know whether my geth private network is not functioning properly or my smart contract is at fault here. Please help

Genesis.json

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 111,
    "eip155Block": 0,
    "eip158Block": 0
  },
  "alloc"      : {},
  "coinbase"   : "0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "difficulty" : "0x10000",
  "gasLimit"   : "9721975",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00"
}
```

Geth initialization

```
geth --datadir ./node1 --keystore keystore init genesis.json
```

Geth console

```
geth --identity "1" --keystore keystore --datadir ./node1 --networkid 111 --port 30303 --nodiscover --rpc --rpcapi "db, personal, eth, web3, debug, miner, net, txpool" --rpccorsdomain="*" --rpcaddr="localhost" --rpcport 8545 --gasprice 20000000000 --allow-insecure-unlock console
```

Truffle configuration

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "111",
      from: "0x2a223397b04891e552f540900bde25383f32f7c8"
    }
  }
};
```

Smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.8;

contract SendMessage {

    struct Message{
        uint ID;
        string text;
        address from;
        address to;
    }
    event countEvent(
        uint indexed messagesCount
    );

    mapping(address => bool) public senders;
    mapping(uint => Message) public messages;
    uint messagesCount;
    address public owner;

    constructor () public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function sendText (string memory _text, address _to) public {
        messagesCount++;
        messages[messagesCount] = Message(messagesCount, _text, msg.sender, _to);
        emit countEvent(messagesCount);

    }

    function getCount () public view returns(uint) {
        return messagesCount;
    }
}
```

When I deploy the smart contract on the geth private network, it gets deployed without any issues, and I can execute sendText function with with following command in truffle console.

```
let app = await SendMessage.deploed()
let accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts()
app.sendText("1st", accounts[1], {from:accounts[0]})
```

Transaction is successfully mined on the blockchain, but transaction log is empty in the transaction receipt. Here is the transaction receipt.

[image]

Assuming from the empty log the function did not succeed and messagesCount did not increase, subsequently when I call getCount() function I get error.

[image]

Geth version: 1.9.3-stable
Go version: go1.12.9
Nodejs version: v10.16.0
Solidity version: 0.5.11
Web3js version: 1.2.1

Comment: 1. I don't see here that you started mining in private network.

2. How did you determine that Transaction is successfully mined  ?  you second image does not shows that this is mined transaction ... it's just *submitted* transaction.  

If you need to get transaction status try :  
 web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(<your subbmited transaction hash>) method  https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt

 returned receipt shuold have blocknumber , which means that transaction is mined and included into block...

Comment: @Baracuda I've tried web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt() and returned receipt had a block number 12 and empty logs. Afterwards I've tried web3.eth.getBlock(12) and the block had corresponding transaction hash in transactions. I should've included these in the question from the start, sorry